# AllAuth's Facebook specific VERIFIED_EMAIL setting ineffective

Tags: facebook, django-allauth

I want the verified status obtained from facebook to set the verified email to true.
Thus I have gone in and changed the setting

```
'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True
```

But when I test the login my verified email is still set to false.  I checked the 'verified' field sent by facebook and it is 'true'.

Any ideas?  This is the last bit I need to fix on my login and it is killing me.

Doc Link
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/7bbd351505fce63797ae20bfbeb005a58bb1cbba#facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Issue was solved over Github and has been included in the project.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/569